# DHCP server does not appear on nmap, no errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp

I have tried to get into Ubuntu thing recently (newest edition), but I've got a problem with DHCP server. I configured the files `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` according to my student book, but seems like it's not working. Nmap does not show my DHCP at all so I assume that's not on at all, but still - there is absolutely no error when I start/restart daemons and services with the settings below:

`interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.110
gateway 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

`dhcpd.conf` file:

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers                  192.168.0.1;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        option domain-search              "example.com";
        option domain-name-servers       192.168.0.100;
        option time-offset              -18000;     # Eastern Standard Time
        range 192.168.0.150 192.168.0.160;
}
```

Ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:7f:f6:20  
          inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fe7f:f620/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1046758 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:647564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1381761035 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:88156037 (88.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:45940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45940 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3127593 (3.1 MB)  TX bytes:3127593 (3.1 MB)
```

isc-dhcp-server:

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Please also provide the content of `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

Comment: @FloHimself  added!

Answer (score 0):

`nmap` is an IP tool, `DHCP` is a method of allocating IP addresses, it doesn't operate at the IP layer as that would make it only useful for entities that no longer need it.  Consequently, `nmap` won't see it.

If you still feel you have a fault, there are tools available to test DHCP servers (eg https://github.com/CyberShadow/dhcptest - never tried by me though)

Comment: The `nmap` bundle includes hundreds of scripts for a variety of networking tasks which also includes DHCP discovery, namely `broadcast-dhcp-discover` and `dhcp-discover`.